# C - the 416 and 647 says expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c

int isValid(const long long phonenumber)
{
    int check = 0;

```
int a;
int p;
a = phonenumber / 10000000;
p = (phonenumber / 10000) % 1000;

if (a = 416 || a = 647 || a = 905) {

    if (p >= 100 || p <= 999) {
        check++
    }

}
return check;
```

}

the 416 and 647 says expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to compare, use '==', not '='.

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: you are welcome!